# Верстка: нижний скролл закрывает часть контента

Tags: html, css, html5, прокрутка

[image: Скролл]

Контент страницы должен иметь высоту в 100% от вьюпорта
Однако при сжимании до размеров по ширине меньше 560px, появляется нижний скролл, который закрывает часть футера.
На данный момент высота контейнера определяется в 100vh.
Каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы при появлении скролла,наш контейнер "ужимался" по высоте на эту высоту скролла, желательно без использования js. Html + css
Вот как сайт выглядит до сжатия, внизу имеется маленький темно-синий футер, который и скрывается скроллом:
[image: До скролла]

Answer (score 0):

если футер вылезает за ширину страницы, стоит применить к нему свойство `max-width: 100%;`

Comment: Нет, имеется в виду то, что под нижним горизонтальным скроллом скрывается футер

Comment: @Макс Прахоцкий, жесткий метод: задайте body {overflow-x: hidden;}, а правильный вариант будет это найти тот элемент который залазиет